# There was an error sending this message to your bot: HTTP status code NotFound

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-bot-service

I tried to deploy the bot in azure. Initially I created a web app bot in azure and then I download the code from azure. After that I added all the production files like .bot, .env, web.config files in my git repository. After that I added my git repository to the azure. I also included the microsoft app id and app password in app.js file and web.config files.

When I start giving test in web chat it is not running properly instead it shows "**There was an error sending this message to your bot: HTTP status code NotFound**"

Where I missed, please help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**I would suggest you to make sure you have followed below steps exactly:**

1. First of all make sure you have configured the messaging endpoint as
   an `https` URL as it does not supports `http`.
2. Check Your Messaging endpoint that you specified and make sure it is
   same as your using in the bot emulator. See the screen shot.

[image]

3. On your bot azure portal go to `Channel` menu and make sure there is
   no issues. see the screen shot below:

[image]

4. Azure portal `Configuration` under `App Service Settings` there will
   be `MicrosoftAppId` and `MicrosoftAppPassword` do not change these
   after downloading it. See the below image

[image]

> **Note:** I also suggest you to [create a new project](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-quickstart?view=azure-bot-service-4.0) on portal and test it on there whether it is working exactly then download it for
>   your enhancement. you could refer [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-quickstart?view=azure-bot-service-4.0). For remote debug please
>   take a look [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/troubleshoot-dotnet-visual-studio#remotedebug). To publish your local project you could refer
>   [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-deploy-az-cli?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=newrg#publish-c-bot-on-app-service-plan-from-visual-studio)

If you still have any concern feel free share in comment. Thank you and happy coding!

Comment: @Prakash Glad to hear. Thank you very much.

Comment: When I connect with microsoft teams channel, teams shows "sending new messages to bot has been disabled by your administrator". How I can test my bot with microsoft teams?

Comment: @Prakash have you connect your channel with Teams?

Answer (score 0):

Go to bot configurations and check the **Enable Streaming Endpoint** checkbox